# Error Eclipse to deploy war of maven project in Weblogic

Tags: eclipse, maven, deployment, weblogic12c, maven-dependency

I get some errors when I try deploy de maven project with the Weblogic server that I added in Eclipse.

I have Java JDK 1.8.0.20 and Weblogic server 12.2.1.2.0

The errors are:

```
<Error> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config> <BEA-000000> <Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getConfigDocuments(ConfigManager.java:764)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:353)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:705)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and

```
<Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101162> <User defined listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:705)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and

```
<Error> <javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config> <BEA-000000> <Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key severe.no_factory_backup_failed
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:450)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:444)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:407)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:559)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

and

```
    <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "24606056810068" for task "13" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and

```
    <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can be something version of dependencies in pom.xml?

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks a lot and best regards.

Comment: Which version of JSF are you using? Do you have it packaged in the war?

Comment: In properties -> Project Faces - >JavaServer Faces I have version 2.2

Comment: Publish in weblogic local from Eclipse. It created auto_generated_ear and auto deploy but it generated exceptions. Thanks in advance @Rouliboy

Comment: Please show your pom.xml :-)

Comment: I don't put it here. Pom.xml is huge. Is a big project that others coworkers can autodeploy with eclipse without problems.
Can be by versions?

`<compileSource>1.7</compileSource>
 <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
 <commons-lang.version>2.6</commons-lang.version>
 <com.oracle.jdbc.version>12.1.0.2</com.oracle.jdbc.version>   
 <sun.jaxws.version>2.2.8</sun.jaxws.version>
 <metro.jaxws.version>2.3</metro.jaxws.version>  
  <org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.version>2.3.1-b20150201.1248</org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.version>`

Comment: show at least your jsf dependencies

Comment: I have not a JSF dependency.

The only dependencies relate to deploy are:

<!-- jax-ws runtime from sun -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
   <version>${sun.jaxws.version}</version>
   <scope>${jaxws.scope}</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!-- jax-ws runtime from glassfish Metro - project tango -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
   <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
   <version>${metro.jaxws.version}</version>
   <scope>${jaxws.scope}</scope>
  </dependency>